# Something like Outer, but symmetric?

Tags: matrix

(I'm simplifying for the sake of an easy explanation, in reality I'm working with much bigger vectors).

If I have a vector $A=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ and a vector $B = \begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}$, and I have a function with two inputs, $f(x,x')$. I want to be able to use a command/function that generates the matrix
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f(a,c) & f(a,d)\\
    f(d,a) & f(b,d)
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
At first I had tried to use `Outer[f,A,B]`, but that gives me
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f(a,c) & f(a,d)\\
    f(b,c) & f(b,d)
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there a built-in function that can do this, or do I need to work on writing my own? I'm still getting used to Mathematica, so if I do have to write my own, any extra help on how I might want to go about that would be great. Ideally, this should be able to scale to large vectors (50-unit vectors or 100-unit vectors) of unequal sizes.

Comment: what is the desired result for `A={a,b,c}` and `B={x,y}`?

Comment: @kglr it should look like `{{f[a,x],f[a,y]}, {f[b,x],f[b,y]}, {f[c,x],f[c,y]}}`

Comment: That's exactly what `Outer[f, A, B]` gives you for that example

Comment: Your original example output is assymetric - `c` occurs only once, and `d` occurs 3 times. `a` or `b` is the first argument 3 times, `d` or `c` once. Please check your expected output in the question.

Comment: You are 100% correct, I misunderstood the problem with my code, sorry!